# Web2Py Redirect after login

Tags: redirect, authorization, web2py

I'm trying to redirect the user to another page (default/news) after the login(on default/index) but no matter how much i tried i couldn't get it done. I'm using the login available in the navbar.

I've added this line to db.py

```
auth.settings.login_next=URL(r=request, c='default', f='news')
```

Everything in the default controller is the same it includes

```
def news():
  message = "Welcome to News!" 
  return locals()
```

I've also tried with this

```
auth.settings.login_next=URL('news')
```

Which doesn't work either. Please Help.

**Edit:**
After searching for days i've found the answer [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.web2py/100907) This is how you do it.

```
#In layout.html change 
<ul id="navbar" class="nav pull-right">{{='auth' in globals() and auth.navbar(mode="dropdown") or ''}}</ul>
# to
<ul id="navbar" class="nav pull-right">{{='auth' in globals() and auth.navbar(mode="dropdown",referrer_actions=None) or ''}}</ul>
```

And again a change in db.py

```
#In db.py add these lines:
auth.settings.login_next = URL('news')
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The `auth.settings.login_next` URL is only a default in case there is no referrer already in the login URL (the referrer is in the "_next" query string variable). The navbar automatically includes a referrer in the auth action links (set to the URL of the current page) -- to override that, you can explicitly specify the`referrer_actions` argument and exclude actions for which the referrer should not be set:

```
{{=auth.navbar(..., referrer_actions=['register', ...])}}
```

Comment: Thank you Anthony, I've tried using that directly in layout.html and index.html,still no success however [this thread](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.web2py/101346) where Rob addresses this issue was very helpful to me.

Comment: Your edit says it works with `referrer_actions=None`. Are you saying it doesn't work if `referrer_actions` is instead a list that *does not* include "login"? It should work either way.

Comment: Yes, it didn't work for me i've changed `{{=auth.navbar(..., referrer_actions=['news'])}}` in layout.html and it doesn't include "login".

Comment: No, `referrer_actions` is not supposed to be a list of URLs to which the user is redirected -- it is a list of Auth actions for which the navbar will include referrer URLs. So, in your db.py, you would still have `auth.settings.login_next = URL('news')`, and in layout.html, you would have something like `{{=auth.navbar(..., referrer_actions=['register', 'profile'])}}`.

Answer (score 1):

It's now April 2016, and while the original question is still highly relevant, it appears that web2py has changed and the modifications suggested above to layout.html are no longer relevant. There is no reference to "auth.navbar" in the standard layout.html.

The good news is, that all one needs to do is include the python code described above in the default.py controller and it works. Note, I put it in the 'user' function, I'm not sure if that is the best place to put it as most comments just say to put it in 'the controller', without specifying a function.

```
def user():
    auth.settings.login_next = URL('default','dashboard')
    return dict(form=auth())
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to redirect to a user's home page after login/signup by putting the following code in my product info page.

This way, when they get redirected back to the welcome-product-info page, I check to see if they came from login or signup and direct them to where they should go.

I'd love to find way to use auth.settings.login_next

#

def info():

```
# If just signed up or just logged in, go to the user's home page and not
# back to this product landing page that referred them
if auth.is_logged_in():

    if  '/default/user/login?_next=/fnd/home/info' in request.env.http_referer:
        redirect( URL( 'user', 'show_campaigns') )

    if  '/default/user/register?_next=/fnd/home/info' in request.env.http_referer:
        redirect( URL( 'user', 'show_campaigns') )


return dict()
```